# Transpose a dataframe based on column entries with sequences

Tags: python, pandas

right now I have a dataframe with two columns:

```
columnA   columnB
:16R:AB     NaN
:20C::XX    S400500
:16X:AB     NaN
:16R:AC     NaN
:16X:AC     NaN
:16R:AB     NaN
:31X::BB    Sema
:16R:AB     Nan
```

I want to transpose the dataframe based on some sequences. The `:16R:AB` till the next `16X:AB` is a sequence, then from `16R:AC`till `16X:AC` and so on. I also want to add a counter/ID then, so that the finale dataframe looks like:

```
Index/Counter :16R:AB :20C::XX :16X:AB :16R:AC :16X:AC :31X:BB
1                 NaN S400500   NaN     NaN    NaN      Nan
2               NaN    NaN       NaN     NaN   NaN      NaN
3               NaN     NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN      Sema
```

Is there any trick to do it? Or is it a manuell loop?

Comment: This might be a case for `df.pivot()`
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html, if you just add a colum that counts the occurences

Comment: I also taught about this, but in pivot it will not have a second row, or? or should I built a counter over the dataframe where I identify every `:16R`and then pivot it?

Comment: yes, I think this counter would work nicely: see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So rebuilding aprototype of your example:
    D = pd.DataFrame([np.random.randint(1,5,20), np.random.randn(20)]).T
    D.columns = ["key", "value"]

key value

4.0 1.017081

4.0 -1.480929

3.0 -1.257809

1.0 -0.683207

...

now we can add a field, that counts the occurance of the same key

```
D["occurance"] = (D.key == 4.0).cumsum()
```

... and then we are able to pivot:

```
D.pivot(index="occurance", columns="key", values=["value"] )
```

Comment: the occurance is not completly correct, for every row it will check in my example if this string already was there, if it is not it will get the occurence 0 and then it starts counting. But in my case it has a chronological order, as you can see for `:31X::BB`this would get a 0 in your case, but I need a 3

Comment: on top I have the following error: `ValueError: Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow`, i think I need to clean the dataframe further in advance to be more focussed

Comment: If you can be sure that there will be no dublicate keys between two ":16R:AB" tokens, you can do the cumsum trick: this will increase the counter every time it hits one of those tokens -- I have adapted the answer; (in your case the  ... == 4.0).cumsum() would be replaced with a ... == ":16R:AB").cumsum()

Comment: is the cumsum formula also possible for several keys? so that he sumsup when he sees either 4.0 or 5.0

Comment: absolutely: the `(D.key == 4.0)` just produces a True False vector where True counts as 1 and False as 0 when using the cumsum function. So to produce the T/F vector you could also do  D.key.isin["A","B","C"].cumsum() and it will be true and add 1 for every token you mention

Comment: D.key.isin(["A","B","C"].cumsum() is the right syntax then, but it is working! thx